# Multiple viewports with same module in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have an app template similar to the following:

```
<template>
    <require from='./templates/header'></require>
    <require from='./templates/navigation'></require>

    <header user.bind="user"></header>
    <navigation></navigation>

    <router-view name="heading"></router-view>

    <div class="page-container>
        <div class="page-content">
            <router-view class="content-wrapper"></router-view>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            Copyright etc.
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I've configured the router to use viewports for the 2 `<router-view>` elements. However I do not want to use 2 different modules. I want to use the same module for both viewports, only with a different view. The idea is that the module controls multiple sections on the page. I managed to do this by specifying the view property on the viewports configuration like so:

```
config.map([
    { 
        name: 'dashboard', 
        route: 'dashboard', 
        viewPorts: { 
            default: { moduleId: './views/dashboard' }, 
            heading: { moduleId: './views/dashboard', view: './views/heading.html' } 
        }, 
        nav: true, 
        title: 'Dashboard' 
    }
]);
```

The problem with this is that the module gets activated twice, which would cause unneccessary processing since I already have all the information I need from the first time. Is there a way that I can configure the viewports to use a different view for the same module (instance)?

Answer (score 0):

All classes in Aurelia are, by default, treated as singletons by Aurelia's dependency injection container. With your example code, your classes will only be instantiated once - so any of your processing code in their constructors or activation events will only occur once.